# UINavigationController creating a blank view out of thin air?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Ok, this one is really weird... I can't show code for it exactly cause it follows a pretty snake-like pattern through subclasses etc, there would be a pile of it.

The important parts are that I push a view controller, which during viewWillAppear pushes another view controller onto the nav controller.

My nav controller is an item in a tab bar. When I press back twice, I wind up at a blank view with the same title as my root view controller, (I have no other views having this title).

I even tested and put a NSLog() in viewWillAppear to make sure it was the same view appearing, but for some reason the mystery blank view is showing up instead of my view. I am able to get the original view back by pressing the button on the tab bar again. (The one that corresponds to the nav controller).

This confuses me greatly, so any help would be appreciated. I will post code if somebody could narrow down what code to put.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you pushing both controller (the original, and the one that it, in turn, pushes) with the animated: flag set to YES? If so, don't do this. The OS gets confused if you try to pile animations like this atop one another.